# How can I use else for `ifne`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

> `ifne` - Run command if the standard input is not empty

If possible I want to run command if the standard input is empty as well; else section for `ifne`.

```
$ printf "hello" | ifne echo "world" 
world
```

Here if the standard input is empty I want to end up in different statement.

`$ printf "" | ifne echo "world" || echo "else"` but it prints nothing. Is it possible to have `else` for `ifne`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> -n
> Reverse operation. Run the command if the standard input is empty. Note that if the standard input is not empty, it is passed through ifne in this case.

```
$ printf "not-empty\n" | ifne    printf "This will print\n"
This will print
$ printf ""            | ifne    printf "This will not print\n"
$ printf "not-empty\n" | ifne -n printf "This will not print\n"
not-empty
$ printf ""            | ifne -n printf "This will print\n"
This will print
```

This lets you do things like:

```
$ dosoemthing | ifne -n printf "There was no output"
```

If you're looking for an if-then-else type of solution, you could pipe stdout into `tee` can call two instances of `ifne`:

```
$ printf "if\n" | tee >(ifne printf "then\n") | ifne -n printf "else\n"
if
then
$ printf ""     | tee >(ifne printf "then\n") | ifne -n printf "else\n"
else
```

But you do also get the original stdout printed too.  That's passing through the `ifne -n` process.

Answer (score 2):

```
( ifne -n sh -c 'exec >&3; echo else' | ifne echo world ) 3>&1
```

If the standard input is not empty then `ifne -n` will not run the `sh …` and it will act like `cat`, passing the input to the second `ifne`. The second `ifne` will run `echo world`. This is quite straightforward.

If the standard input is empty then `ifne -n` will run `sh …`. We couldn't just use `ifne -n echo else | …` because then `else` would get to the second `ifne` and we would get `world` as well. Therefore we use `3>&1` to have the standard output of the entire snippet available even before `|`. It's available as file descriptor 3. `ifne -n echo else >&3 | …` would break the case of non-empty input, where data must get from `ifne -n` to `ifne`. To get what we want, we needed to redirect `echo` but not `ifne -n` itself; hence the inner shell.

You can replace `echo else` with other command(s). You can replace `echo word` with another command (which may be `sh -c …` if you need multiple commands). My point is this answer does not rely on `else` or `world` being printed; replacements may or may not be silent, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to existing answers, note that `ifne` works by attempting to read from stdin, and if something is coming, it starts the command and shovels the data to it in a loop through a pipe.

For most of the types of input however, it should be possible to detect if there's some input without having to read it which would save that extract processing and avoid the pipe.

For instance, you could define a:

```
input_available() {
  perl -MIO::Poll -e '
    $p = IO::Poll->new;
    $p->mask(STDIN, POLLIN);
    $p->poll or die "poll: $!\n";
    exit(1) unless $p->events(STDIN) & POLLIN;
    require "sys/ioctl.ph";
    $n = pack("L", 0);
    ioctl(STDIN, &FIONREAD, $n) or die"ioctl: $!\n";
    $n = unpack("L", $n);
    exit(1) unless $n > 0'
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
some-command |
  if input_available; then
    echo Input available:
    cat
  else
    echo No input available
  fi
```

`poll()` on Linux flags `POLLIN` on pipes only when there is some data, but that's not the case of all systems as some also flag POLLIN on end-of-file. Hence the FIONREAD ioctl to check that there is indeed data. That ioctl doesn't work on all types of input. For instance on Linux, I find it doesn't work on `/dev/null`. It does work on regular files, pipes and tty devices at least though.

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline

```bash
somecommand | ifne echo something
```

... produces output (the string `something`) if `somecommand` writes to standard output.

If the pipeline does not produce any output, then `somecommand` did not produce any output.  This could be caught by `ifne -n`:

```bash
somecommand | ifne echo something | ifne -n echo nothing
```

Testing:

```bash
$ printf 'ok' | ifne echo something | ifne -n echo nothing
something
$ printf '' | ifne echo something | ifne -n echo nothing
nothing
```

Note that this discards the output from the left-most command in the pipeline.  This could be remedied by using something like

```bash
ifne sh -c 'cat;echo something'
```

... as the pipeline's second command, where `cat` is any command that should receive the output from the left-hand side.

This also relies on the fact that the last command is not given any input in the case where the 1st command does not produce any output.